# Multiple "user option" parameters on the same function

Tags: jquery, jcrop

No idea if my terminology is correct in the question title, sorry. Feel free to amend.

I need to know how to assign multiple parameters on a `jquery` function.

My function currently reads as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#crop-me').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 130 / 170,
        minSize: [130, 170],
        setSelect: [260, 340, 0, 0],
        onChange: showCoords,
        onSelect: showCoords
    });
    function showCoords(c) {
        ...
    }
    function updatePreview(d) {
        ...
    }
});
```

But I also need to assign `updatePreview` to `onChange:` and `onSelect:`. How do I do this?

I've tried the following:

`onChange: showCoords updatePreview`

`onChange: [showCoords, updatePreview]`

```
onChange: showCoords,
onChange: updatePreview
```

But none of those three ways seem to work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do here is pass an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_expression_.28function_operator.29) and within it, you can call the other functions you want.

It would look something like this:

```
$('#crop-me').Jcrop({
    ...
    onChange: function(){ 
      showCoords();
      updatePreview();
    },
    ...
});
```

If you want to persist all of the arguments passed to the functions, you can use the [`arguments` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) that exists in every function. This variable is an array-like containing all the arguments passed to the function.

```
$('#crop-me').Jcrop({
    ...
    onChange: function(){ 
      showCoords( arguments );
      updatePreview( arguments );
    },
    ...
});
```

---

The [MDN JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) has this to say about the arguments variable:

> The arguments object is a local variable available within all functions; arguments as a property of Function can no longer be used.
>
> You can refer to a function's arguments within the function by using the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at 0.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide an anonymous function to that parameter which calls both functions:

```
onChange: function(c) {
    showCoords(c);
    updatePreview(c);
}
```